# How can I pipe the hostname into a call to SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to write a script to automate connecting to various remote instances but am having a hard time piping the resulting hostname to as an argument to ssh. I'm basically trying to do the following:

```
echo "example.com" | xargs -I {} ssh {}
```

I also tried a bunch of combinations but to no avail. The closest I got was with the following but it loses interactivity.

```
echo "example.com" | xargs -0 ssh -t -t
```

The end goal is to be able to have a script that will return a hostname/ipaddress that can then be connected to via ssh. For example:

```
my_random_script | ... ssh
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want a simple shell script to handle this?

Comment: I had an old solution using a shell script but I want that first part to be via Python since I'm more comfortable with it. I suppose I can wrap them together into a shell script but it seems there must be a way to do it using a combination of pipes and xargs. Maybe not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you want to run:

```
ssh `echo example.com`
ssh `your_random_script`
```

When you insert some command into back-quotes, this command is executed, and result stored in unnamed variable. For save/reuse, you can invoke something like:

```
VAR=`your_random_script`
ssh $VAR
```

Comment: Yea - I know this works but the first part returns a dynamic hostname. So for example "random_script_that_returns_an_ip | xargs .."

Comment: But, you can run "ssh \`your_random_script\`" instead of echo.

Comment: Awesome - that worked. Thanks! I imagine the backticks just execute everything in between them? Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll upvote/accept it.